# How to remove background from Complex in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background, background-removal

I have tried to remove the background from the image below but it just disfigures the image.  I have used adjustments->Replace color,  Hue and saturation layer,  magnetic lasso and manually erasing around the edges.  Would anyone have an easy solution to removing this background and replacing it with white ?[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: White is going to be a real struggle, as the reflective parts already have the dark background reflected in them, so it's not going to look realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be difficult to obtain a clean selection using the kind of selection tools you have already tried.  In cases such as this the human eye and manual editing skills can trump anything automated.

Don't mess around with manual erasing. You can get much cleaner results by creating a vector mask manually, using the Pen Tool to create the curves.

Example:

[image]

The dark shadows around the object are a little problematic, caused by lack of reflections from the dark background unfortunately, but these could be retouched. Here I used the Dodge tool, Sponge tool, Clone tool, and the Smudge tool.

[image]

Finally, perhaps add a drop shadow

[image]

Comment: Nice. Now you just need to add a drop shadow!

Comment: @Wolff - yes, will add one in a minute.

Comment: Thanks.  Ive never used a layer mask.  Can i also ask what you mean by using a pen for the curves.  This is exactly what i want to do.

Comment: The Pen Tool is used for making paths (with Bézier curves) to create a vector mask. It's too complex to teach you here. There are tutorials on youtube on how to use it, and on layer masking.